# Installing Kernel Headers offline - Linux Kali

Tags: kali-linux, header-file

I need to install Kernel Headers to install nvidia graphics driver to run linux kali.

Now here is the tricky part, it must be done completely offline. I have no idea how to do it. Kali is freshly installed on the harddrive and I have no connection to the internet from kali itself. But I have access to internet to download files and put them on a usb stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download yourself from: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux-latest/, and bring it to kali machine via e.g. usb storage.

Then, install the downloaded .deb file with (change the name to whatever you downloaded):

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-686_4.8+76+kali1_i386.deb
```

Comment: thank you a lot, what is the command to actually install. When I try to "apt install /folder/file" or "apt-get install /folder/file" I always get errors.

Cheers

Comment: You can install with `dpkg -i /path/to/pakckage/full_packagesname` as Ipor Sircer wrote. With apt you mußt do it so `apt -o Dir::Cache::archives="/Path/to/folder/" install linux-headers-686` Path to folder means where your Deb-Package is locatet.

Comment: depends on bc; however:
  Package bc is not installed.